# YII2. Using URL's in js

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have the following javascript code

```
$(".order-event-btn").click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
url: "URL",
type: "POST",
data: {
    eventId: $(e.target).attr('data-event-id'),
},
success: function(data) {
    //Some code
},
error: function(data) {
    //Some code
},
});
});
```

I include this script using "BookAsset".

Here

```
url: "URL",
```

I need URL to the action "book-event" in the controller Book.

On the server, I can do this:

```
 Url::to('/book/book-event')
```

But how do I get URL on client side?

**There is an solution:**

**1.** js file include via BookAsset.

**2.** in view file I register bundle:

```
\frontend\assets\BookAsset::register($this);
```

**3.** in view file define a bookEventURL variable. Now it is available in the js-file.

```
$this->registerJs('var bookEventURL = ' . Url::to('/book/book-event') . ';');
```

**But I do not like this solution.**
What will happen when I use this script in many views. I have to define a variable bookEventURL in each view?

**My Question**. Is it possible to bind js-variables to my BookAsset. When I register my BookAsset in the view, in page source code automatically insert next code:

```
<script>var bookEventURL = "http://example.com/book-event/";</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you put that into the layout file instead of views? main.php can have `$this->registerJs('var baseUrl = ' . Url::home(true) . ';');`. That way, the base url is included everywhere. Then you can build your URL whereever you need.

Comment: Because I do not need this variable on all pages, but only a few. If I put it in the main.php, it will be everywhere.

Comment: Yes, the baseUrl.. ?

Comment: and may be this one is related.. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7649

Comment: The solution should be universal. For example, if I change 'rules' urlManager, I need to change URL's for all scripts. URL's is still appropriate, and if I have to transfer large objects on the client... sorry for my english :)

Comment: Well there isn't a way to do it currently as far as I know. They are working on it btw. Just see this issue : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10460

Comment: Do you think there will be a good solution to write a controller, which will give the URL's for the Ajax-requests from the client? js function that will get url from server via ajax.

Comment: That's a great idea IMHO. it can just have one method. Pass the section you need path for and it will return the path. The only problem would be that there will be a lag before the actual request is sent.

Answer (score 5):

A proper way of doing this is to add the needed information in your button tag, e.g. :

```
<?= Button::widget([
    'label' => 'Order',
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'order-event-btn',
        'data' => [
            'url' => Url::to(['book/book-event']),
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

And in your js code :

```
$(".order-event-btn").click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    // ...
});
```

But if you really want to "bind js-variables" to your `BookAsset`, you could simply override `register()` :

```
public static function register($view)
{
    parent::register($view);
    $view->registerJs('var bookEventURL = ' . json_encode(Url::to(['book/book-event'])) . ';');
}
```

Comment: It still does not resolve the problem that the code isn't DRY. He is to write that data url everywhere he needs the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use it in different places of your application than I guess you should place it in the layout.